# Assigning a propterty to itself warning in Xcode when assigning member in class Initializer

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am learning Swift following along with the [Bloc.io Swiftris](https://www.bloc.io/tutorials/swiftris-build-your-first-ios-game-with-swift#!/chapters/679) tutorial.

I have created a Array2D class to for the game board

```
// Generic arrays in Swift are actually of type struct, not class but we need a class in this case since class objects are 
// passed by reference whereas structures are passed by value (copied).
// Our game logic will require a single copy of this data structure to persist across the entire game.
// Notice that in the class' declaration we provide a typed parameter: <T>. 
// This allows our array to store any type of data and therefore remain a general-purpose tool.
class Array2D<T> {
    let columns : Int
    let rows : Int

    //  an actual Swift array; it will be the underlying data structure which maintains references to our objects.
    // ? in Swift symbolizes an optional value. An optional value is just that, optional.
    // nil locations found on our game board will represent empty spots where no block is present.
    var array: Array<T?>

    init(colums: Int, rows: Int) {
        self.columns = columns // !! Assigning a property to itself. 
        self.rows = rows
        // we instantiate our internal array structure with a size of rows * columns. 
        // This guarantees that Array2D can store as many objects as our game board requires, 200 in our case.
        array = Array<T?>(count:rows * columns, repeatedValue: nil)
    }
}
```

However Xcode shows a `Assigning a property to itself.` warning by this line:

```
self.columns = columns
```

I´m a bit perplexed by the warning, isn´t that exactly what I intended to do? What does the warning mean?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've made a typo in the constructor definition.

The name of the parameter in your constructor is `colums`.

Either change that to columns or change the offending line to

```
self.columns = colums
```

and it should work

Comment: A bit embarrassing. Thanks!

Comment: @max take it ease, it just happend to me few seconds ago :D

Answer (score 2):

There a typo in your init declaration:

```
init(colums: Int, rows: Int)
          ^
```

you wrote `colums` instead of `columns`

Comment: Both answers are almost identical but @Rajeev Bhatia was faster. Thanks a lot anyway!

Answer (score -2):

see the correct writing of the word in all the code....in any Apps

in all classes , methods etc ! dont say Tnank you!